# docker container to hold multiple database

Tags: postgresql, docker

I am trying to launch a docker container to hold 2 databases( PostgreSQL). I am executing the .sql scripts by injecting it to docker-initdb. But Only one script gets executed.

**Dockerfile:**

```
FROM postgres
ENV POSTGRES_USER postgres 
ENV POSTGRES_PASSWORD postgres 

COPY /appdb.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/

COPY /userdb.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
```

Here only `userdb.sql` executes. How can I change it to make both scripts execute at one go?

Please help

Comment: Post the complete log output. Also make sure you have read all of: https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres/ "Initialization scripts"

Comment: I agree the initialization scripts is the way to go, there you can make sure both your SQL files are executed.   Otherwise you would need to create your own custom image and add `supervisor` as your initialization tool `CMD/ENTRYPOINT` - This tool can run multiple scripts/apps etc on startup of container.